# using mutex in c++ concurrency

Tags: c++, multithreading

Try to understand the details of concurrency programming using c++. Came across this piece of code and got stuck with understanding one line of the code. Attached is the details:

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_stack
{

private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    threadsafe_stack(){}
    threadsafe_stack(const threadsafe_stack& other)
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);  
    //////////////////why <1>locking other.m not this->m <2> or locking both
    data=other.data;
    }
    // some other codes
}
```

Comment: It is a constructor, so nothing else can be accessing `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `this` instance of class `threadsafe_stack` is being constructed for the first time, so you can be sure noone else is accessing it's fields, so it does not need to use `this->mutex`. However, someone else can be using the `other` instance at that time, so it's a good idea to use that mutex to protect `other`'s `data` field from concurrent access.

That is, the copy constructor, for which the code you see, is invoked on construction of object based on some other instance, e.g.:

```
threadsafe_stack copy_of_stack{ original_stack };
```

Now, noone else is able to call a method in context of `copy_of_stack` instance until the copy-constructor's execution finishes.

The mutex field of each `threadsafe_stack` is intended to protect from concurrent access the content of the instance that the mutex belongs to.

Now, imagine that there is some other thread that operates on `original_stack` instance:

```
while (true)
{
    original_stack.push(123);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

where the `push` method looks like this:

```
void threadsafe_stack<T>::push(const T& value)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ this->m };
    data.push(value);
}
```

As you can see, each `push` operation protects **it's own** `data` field. The same instance of field `data` is being accessed by copy-constructor of the `copy_of_stack` instance. Using **the same mutex** makes the access mutually exclusive in terms of access to `data` field. In other words: in `data = other.data;` noone else can be accessing `data` at this time, but someone can be accessing `other.data`, this is why we lock only one (that `other`'s) mutex.